# Better Way To Append To A String

Tags: php

When I use a `foreach` to add content to a string i always use `$x .= 'content'` but first I have the declare that variable `$x = ''` which seems like an extra line of code that isn't needed. Is there a better way to do this?

Here's a good example:

```
$options = array('Link 1', 'Link 2', 'Link 3')
$output = '';
foreach($options as $value) $output .= '<a href="#">' . $value . '</a>';
echo $output;
```

Comment: No, the variable initialization is the proper way.

Comment: Is there anyways I could make it part of the foreach somehow?

Comment: No, not with a foreach. You could use a for loop, but that would actually be more code

Comment: Is declaring a variable bother you that much?

Comment: I'm cleaning code, not a big deal, just was wondering mostly. I want to make the neatest code possible. I kind of have a OCD for it.

Comment: You have to declare variable before you can using it. This is THE way. Is not about neatest code or not, is THE way. I bet you never turn on `error_reporting(E_ALL)` in your development machine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you could try a ternary operator, like below, but again, this is more code. Unless I'm mistaken there isn't a 'non' declaration way.

```
$options = array('Link 1', 'Link 2', 'Link 3');
foreach($options as $value) (isset($output) ? $output .= '<a href="#">' . $value . '</a>' : $output = '<a href="#">' . $value . '</a>');
echo $output;
```

Comment: Even if it's a bit more code, it looks better with on less line. I suppose the different between less lines compared to less code isn't good and it would probably be better to have less code but I just want the most neatest code possible.

Comment: You are correct, but then, code neatness is always a matter of opinion ;)

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this, if you want it in one line:

```
foreach() {
    $output = isset($output) ? $output . $more : $more;
}
```

but this is the same, just written with the ternary operator :-)

Answer (score 0):

No, not with clean code. In theory, you could leave the line "$output = ''" away. The result would be the same. However this is very bad style, leads easier to bugs and for these reasons generates PHP warnings of level NOTICE (which are not displayed by default).